# How to Read CSV file using Power Automate?

Tags: csv, sharepoint, power-automate, power-platform, document-library

I have added CSV file to SharePoint Documents library.

I needs to read that CSV file using Power Automate / Flow.

I have created Power Automate flow. Below is the screenshot fro the same.

[image]

Which CSV parser do i need to use for read data from file content action?

Can anyone help me for the same?

Thanks

Comment: You can retrieve the contents of the CSV file using the **Get file content** action in Power Automate/Microsoft Flow, and then using the **Parse CSV** action to transform the file contents into a structured format that can be used in subsequent actions in your flow. For instance, you may send emails, update a database, or add items to another SharePoint list using the parsed data.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have trued the same way which attached in my question. There are many CSV parser. Can you please suggest me which one is better? Thanks

Comment: Just try one of them.  There's also the `Advanced Data Operations` connector which has an action for it.  That connector is worth the money if you're willing to pay.  It has a bunch of great transformation options.

Comment: Thanks for response. I need to read that CSV file using Power Automate / Flow. without using any third-party actions.

Comment: Why can you not use a third party action?  If that's a problem for you then you'll need to look at doing it yourself.  You can create an Azure Function and use it otherwise I think you're a bit stuck.  You'd need to extend beyond PA anyway, i.e. use SQL or something and try and get it done that way.

Comment: Thanks fro response. Third party actions are not free. They have some limitations like triggers 50 times in week etc. So, i need to create functionality without any restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to retrieve the content of the CSV without a premium connector you could use an expression to convert the $content property of the Get File Content action into a string value. You can use the [base64tostring](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#base64tostring) function for this.

Below is an example

```
base64tostring(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body']['$content'])
```

[image]