Update item ERROR - from csv. to Microsoft LIST
I am trying to import CSV data into a SharePoint List using Power Automate, following this YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3aQf17ptAs&t=845s):
enter image description here
The key difference between the tutorial and my implementation is that I am introducing a CONDITION to verify whether the data is new or if it needs to be updated:
enter image description here
wMy filter query is as follows:
Title eq 'concat(split(item(),',')?[02],'|',split(item(),',')?[04])'
My condition is:
length(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'])* is greater than 0*

If the data is new, the CREATE ITEM action works as expected.
If the data already exists, I get the following error:

enter image description here
enter image description here
I have tried the CONDITION approach using an Excel file instead of a CSV, and it worked without any issues.
However, when I attempt to import the CSV data, I encounter the error described above.
Could you please help me identify what might be going wrong with the CSV import? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

CSV's work differently than Excel files when trying to retrieve them from SharePoint in Power Automate. For your specific scenario, you will have use an expression to convert the csv to a readable output. I am not sure what type of .csv you have, but here is an example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772182/how-to-read-csv-file-using-power-automate
